# Properly echo a bunch of CSS options using PHP?

Tags: php, css, echo

Consider a following function with **one option** echoed out:

```
function dynamic_options() {
$getheadercolor = get_header_textcolor();
$options_social = get_option('sandbox_theme_social_options');   
$wrapper_background_color = get_option('wrapper_background_color');

if($getheadercolor !='blank'){
echo '<style type="text/css">';
}

  if($getheadercolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."#header a{   
     color:#$getheadercolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $getheadercolor

   if($getheadercolor !='blank'){
        echo "\n".'</style>';
   }

}// End Dynamic options
```

It outputs something like this into my header (*it works flawlessly and does exactly as I want*)

```
<style type="text/css">

#header a{

 color:#30409b;
}
</style>
```

Now here is the problem: This function will not have only one option but a **bunch of options** (20-30 options). So to illustrate my point let's say that for now my function will have **five** options. So it will look like this:

```
function dynamic_options() {
$getheadercolor = get_header_textcolor();
$options_social = get_option('sandbox_theme_social_options');   
$wrapper_background_color = get_option('wrapper_background_color');

//My main "problem" is an IF Statement below because it will look like a mess
//With 20 options or more and with all those OR inside it... 
if($getheadercolor !='blank' || $sitecolor !='' || $textcolor !='' 
|| $backgroundcolor !='' || $menucolor !=''){
echo '<style type="text/css">';
}

  if($getheadercolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."#header a{   
     color:#$getheadercolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $getheadercolor

     if($sitecolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."#wrapper{    
     background-color:#$sitecolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $sitecolor

     if($textcolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n".".entry p{    
     color:#$textcolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $textcolor

     if($backgroundcolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."body{    
     background-color:#$backgroundcolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $backgroundcolor

     if($menucolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n".".nav{    
     background-color:#$menucolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $menucolor

   //So to even close my style tag i need a bunch of those statments
   if($getheadercolor !='blank' || $sitecolor !='' || $textcolor !='' 
       || $backgroundcolor !='' || $menucolor !=''){
        echo "\n".'</style>';
   }
```

So my function above *will work* but this part 
`if($getheadercolor !='blank' || $sitecolor !='' || $textcolor !='' 
           || $backgroundcolor !='' || $menucolor !='')` just seem wrong to me. 
Because this IF statement will have more than **20** options I am afraid that my code will be Slow and Inefficient.
My PHP Force is not strong... so my only (not ideal) solution is to simply omit those two IF statement like so:

```
     function dynamic_options() {
     $getheadercolor = get_header_textcolor();
     $options_social = get_option('sandbox_theme_social_options');  
     $wrapper_background_color = get_option('wrapper_background_color');
     echo '<style type="text/css">';    

 if($getheadercolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."#header a{   
     color:#$getheadercolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $getheadercolor

     if($sitecolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."#wrapper{    
     background-color:#$sitecolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $sitecolor

     if($textcolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n".".entry p{    
     color:#$textcolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $textcolor

     if($backgroundcolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n"."body{    
     background-color:#$backgroundcolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $backgroundcolor

     if($menucolor !='blank') {
     echo "\n".".nav{    
     background-color:#$menucolor;
     }";     
  }//End If $menucolor

     echo "\n".'</style>';  
}// End Dynamic options
```

Now my code **without** those IF statements *will work too* but now problem is, if there are no options my function will still echo an **empty** CSS style tag inside my header:`<style type="text/css"></style>` and that is something I don't want.

Can somebody give me an example or advice for making this function work better?

P.S. I am considering myself as PHP *noob* so if someone can give me a nice and clear advice or example it would be much appreciated! Thank You!!!

Comment: Use [less](http://lesscss.org/) with [php](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of if(){} statements I use switch() { case.. } statements only because with the code that you have supplied it looks neater.

```
<?php
   function dynamic_options() {
       echo "<style type='text/css'>
       $css = array( 'headercolor'=>'blank',
                     'options_social'=>'blank',
                     'wrapper_background_color'=>'blank' );
       $css['headercolor'] = 'c0c0c0'; // get_header_textcolor();
       //$css['options_social'] = 'dont set this one'; //get_option('sandbox_theme_social_options');
       $css['wrapper_background_color'] = 'f00'; //get_option('wrapper_background_color');

    foreach( $css as $itm => $value ) {
        if( $value != 'blank' ) {
            switch( $itm ) {
                case 'headercolor'              : echo "\n"."#header a{color:#{$value};}"; break;
                case 'wrapper_background_color' : echo "\n"."#wrapper{background-color:#{$value};}";  break;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</style>";
  }
?>
```

It doesn't matter if the final output is  as it makes no difference to the browser.

Thanks for the offer of the bounty but I'll take a raincheck on it - I might need your help one day.

Comment: Thank you Jeff I have never used foreach statement before it looks a lot clearer to me now, I learned something new from you:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using an associative array for the options:

```
$css = array( 'headercolor'=>'', 'options_social'=>'' .... );
```

set the value as you are now doing:

```
$getheadercolor = get_header_textcolor();
$options_social = get_option('sandbox_theme_social_options');   
$wrapper_background_color = get_option('wrapper_background_color');
```

Then iterate over the values using a foreach() statement. This way you get the property name and it's value.

Comment: Yes I was thinking to make it that way but I am not skilled in PHP that much... if you can clarify a bit how can I do a foreach() loop for my example I will gladly award you a bounty (50);

Answer (score 1):

you should store your options into associative array and remove items which contain 'blank' or  '' string. so, just echo if array is not empty.

```
$options = array();
$options['header_color'] = get_header_color();
$options['text_color'] = get_text_color();
$remove = array('','blank');
$options = array_diff($options, $remove);
if (!empty($options)) {
echo '<style type="text/css">';
if(isset($options['header_color'])) {
    echo "\n"."#header a{   
    color:#".$options['header_color'].";
    }";     
}
if(isset($options['text_color'])) {
    echo "\n".".entry p{   
    color:#".$options['text_color'].";
    }";     
}
   echo '</style>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put the styles into a variable. After the execution of your if-statements you can check if the variable is empty. If not, you can print the style tag.